# C++ Sorting dynamic array of strings - sort does not work

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I want to sort a dynamic array of strings, provided with std::cin.

I don't know what is wrong with my code, but the array does not get sorted.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void sort_array(string *array);

int main() {
    cout << "Number of names to enter: " << endl;
    int nr_names;
    cin >> nr_names;
    string *names = new (nothrow) string[nr_names];

    if (names == nullptr) {
        cout << "Memory alocation failed" << endl;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_names; i++) {
            cout << "Enter a name: " << endl;
            cin >> names[i];
        }
        cout << "Entered names are: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_names; i++) {
            cout << names[i] << endl;
        }

        sort_array(names);

        cout << "Sorted names: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_names; i++) {
            cout << names[i] << endl;
        }
        delete[] names;
    }
    return 0;
}

void sort_array(string *array) {
    const int arSize = (sizeof(*array) / sizeof(array[0]) - 1);
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < arSize; startIndex++) {
        int smallestIndex = startIndex;

        for (int currentIndex = startIndex+1; currentIndex < arSize; currentIndex++) {
            if (array[currentIndex] < array[smallestIndex]) {
                smallestIndex = currentIndex;
            }
        }
    swap(array[startIndex], array[smallestIndex]);
    }
}
```

The sorting method works with a fixed array. So I think that there could be some problems with the dynamic memory allocation(which I just started to study)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string array[5] ={"Mike", "Andrew", "Bob", "Nick", "Matthew"};
    const int arSize = 5;
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < arSize; startIndex++) {
        int smallestIndex = startIndex;

        for (int currentIndex = startIndex+1; currentIndex < arSize; currentIndex++) {
            if (array[currentIndex] < array[smallestIndex]) {
                smallestIndex = currentIndex;
            }
        }
        swap(array[startIndex], array[smallestIndex]);
    }
    //print the sorted array - works
    for(int i = 0; i< arSize; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-de

Comment: `const int arSize = (sizeof(*array) / sizeof(array[0]) - 1);` this isn't the array size!

Comment: I would suggest using `std::vector` (dynamic array library class) instead of a raw dynamic array, unless you specifically want to learn about dynamic memory management.

Comment: Thank you Paul and Justin. I will read more about debugging and std::vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `void sort_array(string *array)` the array doesn't get sorted because `const int arSize = (sizeof(*array) / sizeof(array[0]) - 1);` isn't the array size. It is ... 0.

it should be `const int arSize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` but only works if `array` is an array, not a pointer on elements.

so your loop is never executed (So you have to pass the size along)

As Justin commented, since you're using C++ and advanced `swap` stuff, `std::vector` is the way to pass an array with its size.

Comment: Thank you! *array points to first element of the array so that's why it results in 0. I added a new param to sort_array function, "int length", which asks for the length of the array at runtime, and seems to fix the problem. I will also study std::vector in the near future.